# How do i restrict the user without passing the middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

```
const restricted = async (x, myID) => {
     try {
          const i = x.posts.forEach((a, b, c, d) => {
               let lol = x.PrivacySettings.restricted.some(x => { return x; })
               let lole = a.comments.some(x => { return x; }).postedBy;

               if (lol === lole && myID !== lol || a.postBy) {
                    const FU = a.comments.filter((a, b, c, d) => {
                         return a.postedBy === lol;
                    });
                    return FU;
               } else {
                    return;
               }
          });
          return i;
     } catch (ex) {
          console.log(ex.message);
          res.status(200).json('something went wrong');
     }
}
```

**So i have this function above, now how do i check if the user is restricted or not?
i have to implement this function in all the comment routes so how can i do it other than
making it a middleware**

Comment: shall pass it in a if-else condition ?

Comment: _"so how can i do it other than making it a middleware"_. Still make a middleware.